# How to check if my program is running as admin/sudo C#/.NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, cross-platform

How can I check if my program is running as admin/sudo? I'm making a cross-platform C# program that needs to run as admin in order for it to work. It will be running on Windows, macOS, and Linux so I don't know how and .NET Core doesn't seem to have namespaces as other solutions I found which were for .NET Framework/Windows-only.

Comment: permissions are often much more complicated that "admin" and "not admin". One way would be to attempt the behavior you want when starting, and if it fails quit the app with an error.

Answer (score 4):

Try this one:

```
static class RootChecker
{
    [DllImport("libc")]
    public static extern uint getuid();

    public static bool IsRoot()
    {
        if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
        {
            bool isAdmin;
            using (var identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
            {
                var principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
                isAdmin = principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
            }

            return isAdmin;
        }
        else
        {
            return getuid() == 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you missed the cross-platform requirement of the question.

Comment: It's still very wrong. You want `geteuid` whenever you are making any permission checks. Your implementation will fail under `sudo`, for example. See https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~daw/papers/setuid-usenix02.pdf for more information.

Comment: I've checked this OSX and it works with sudo:

` $ ~/ sudo dotnet ./dotnet-core-root-test.dll
True`

Comment: @OmairMajid TL;DR - far too detailed an article to understand for the average user or provide an explanation. While getuid and geteuid have differences in certain cases, it's definitely not "very wrong". In this example it would depend if setuid bit has been set on the 'dotnet' executable, which isn't recommended.

"Since the dotnet host can execute any arbitrary IL code, it probably isn't a good idea to set the setuid bit on it, as that would mean you could execute any code as the owner of the dotnet executable." https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/26268

Comment: That's a good point! But with global tools (2.x) and apphosts entering the picture (3.x), I still think it's a good idea to begin with correct code.